# How to avoid "org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException: Update conflict"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I wrote a plugin which does some bulk changes to legacy code. The changes are done in a loop over a Collection of `ICompilationUnits`, which are processed one by one. Run multiple times, it is possible that the same compilation units are changed again.

The command works fine, if run for the first time. After that, when I run the command again I get a `JavaModelException`.

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException: Update conflict
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:784) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:391) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

What can I do to avoid this exception? My code handling the code changes looks like this:

```
public void process(ICompilationUnit cu, SubMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    monitor.setWorkRemaining(7);
    try {
        cu.becomeWorkingCopy(monitor.newChild(1));

        CompilationUnit unit = EclipseUtil.parseAst(cu, monitor.newChild(1));
        ASTRewrite rewrite = ASTRewrite.create(unit.getAST());
        ImportRewrite importRewrite = ImportRewrite.create(unit, true);

        // Do the Work
        processSearchResults(unit, rewrite, importRewrite, monitor.newChild(1));

        cu.applyTextEdit(rewrite.rewriteAST(), monitor.newChild());
        TextEdit importEdit = importRewrite.rewriteImports(monitor.newChild(1));
        cu.applyTextEdit(importEdit, monitor.newChild(1));

        if (monitor.isCanceled())
            cu.discardWorkingCopy();
        else
            cu.commitWorkingCopy(false, monitor.newChild(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        cu.discardWorkingCopy();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

All instances are freshly read. The plugin itself does not cache anything. Is there something I forgot to do, like refreshing or closing a resource? Maybe the unit AST itself?

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated in `CommitWorkingCopyOperation.verify`:

```
if (cu.hasResourceChanged() && !this.force) {
  return new JavaModelStatus(IJavaModelStatusConstants.UPDATE_CONFLICT);
}
```

`hasResourceChanged` is checking the time stamp stored in the compilation unit against the time stamp of the source file. So it looks like you are picking up an out of date compilation unit.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your input. How can I make sure, that the compilation unit gets "refreshed"? I see ICompilationUnit.reconcile(...) but this seems to be something else.